# AWS ECR GetAuthorizationToken questions

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

When I run the command to push an image to ECR, I get the following error.

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-northeast-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 123123.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com
```

The access_key and secret_key are properly registered.
IAM already contains the following policy as well

```
AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser
```

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:iam::123123:user/example.gmail.com is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: * with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The IAM user that you are using has an identity policy with an explicit `Deny` action for the `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` action, which basically overrides the `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser` policy.

> How can I solve this problem?

The faulty policy needs to be changed so that the `Deny` action is removed.

See more: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html